# Problem with HLSL looping/sampling

Tags: directx, xna, hlsl, shader

I have a piece of HLSL code which looks like this:

```
float4 GetIndirection(float2 TexCoord)
{
    float4 indirection = tex2D(IndirectionSampler, TexCoord);

    for (half mip = indirection.b * 255; mip > 1 && indirection.a < 128; mip--)
    {
        indirection = tex2Dlod(IndirectionSampler, float4(TexCoord, 0, mip));
    }
    return indirection;
}
```

The results I am getting are consistent with that loop only executing once. I checked the shader in PIX and things got even more weird, the yellow arrow indicating position in the code gets to the loop, goes through it once, and jumps back to the start, at that point the yellow arrow never moves again but the cursor moves through the code and returns a result (a bug in PIX, or am I just using it wrong?)

I have a suspicion this may be a problem to do with texture reads getting moved outside the loop by the compiler, however I thought that didn't happen with tex2Dlod since I'm setting the LOD manually :/

So:

1) What's the problem?

2) Any suggested solutions?

Comment: Are you compiling against SM3 or SM4? IF this is directx 10 you might want to set the D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG and D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION flags when compiling your shader as this might help you track down the problem in PIX.

Comment: Compiling to SM3 using DirectX9, which is the highest I can use since this is XNA

Comment: Ok, that wasn't immediately obvious since you tagged it both DirectX and XNA ;)

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that this issue would be one that a lot of DirectX people would have something to contribute to (like yourself, I guess?), so I tagged it as such :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved, it was a simple coding mistake, I needed to increase mip level on each iteration, not decrease it.

```
float4 GetIndirection(float2 TexCoord)
{
    float4 indirection = tex2D(IndirectionSampler, TexCoord);

    for (half mip = indirection.b * 255; mip > 1 && indirection.a < 128; mip++)
    {
        indirection = tex2Dlod(IndirectionSampler, float4(TexCoord, 0, mip));
    }
    return indirection;
}
```